# Apply a function on all the element of the environment

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm working with multiple dataframes, all of them stocked in the global environment.
I seek for a way to use a function on all of them, without having to write the function for each one, ie applying a function to all the object of the environment instead of writing one line for each object.

Here's the environment I'm working on:

[image]

Comment: Something like this: `lapply(mget(ls()), function(i) doStuff(i))` put all dataframes into a list, then apply a function.

Comment: In addition to zx8754's comment, you may want to filter for objects in the environment that are indeed data frames, using something like `eapply(.GlobalEnv,is.data.frame)`.